# Nhibernate update integer field = field+1

Tags: nhibernate

I have a simple integer field mapped in nhibernate.
I want to make an update that nhibernate will translate it to +1;

```
UPDATE table_name SET revision=revision + 1 [WHERE Clause]....
```

Is it possible to make such thing? Force nhibernate incrementing field by N on update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, that you are talking about "make update without loading the entity", the answer is yes, we do have DML: [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct). Small extract:

> ... automatic and transparent object/relational mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies that the object state is available in memory, hence manipulating (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect in-memory state. However, NHibernate provides methods for bulk SQL-style DML statement execution which are performed through the Hibernate Query Language (HQL)...

It is a way, how to use the mapping we have, creating the HQL describing the update, execute this on the DB Engine directly, without any data load.

Converted example:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();


string hqlUpdate = "update TheMappedEntity e set e.Revision=(e.Revision + 1) where...";
int updatedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .SetString( ... // set params
        .ExecuteUpdate();

tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

The biggest advantage is that we are working with the Entity (mapped one) not with raw SQL